# Is the relation $\Psi: M_2(\mathbb{Z^*}) \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ a Function

Tags: matrices, functions

*Determine if the following is a function*

*Let $\Psi: M_2(\mathbb{Z^*}) \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ by $\Psi\big( \left[\begin{smallmatrix} a&0\\ 0&b\end{smallmatrix}\right]\big) = \frac{a}{b}$ $\thinspace$ where $M_2(\mathbb{Z^*}) = \left\{\begin{smallmatrix} a&b\\ c&d\end{smallmatrix} | \thinspace a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z^*}\right\}$*

I propose that $\Psi$ is not a function, because there does not exist a matrix of the form $\left[\begin{smallmatrix} a&0\\ 0&b\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ by definition of the set $M_2$. In other words, there is no matrix of the form $\left[\begin{smallmatrix} a&0\\ 0&b\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ to serve as the preimage for the relation f.

Answer (score 0):

Your relation $\Psi$ is only defined on a subset of $M_2(\mathbb{Z}^*)$. Hence it is not a function in the usual sense.

(Also, I don't follow your own reasoning: "there does not exist a matrix of the form $\left[\begin{smallmatrix} a&0\\ 0&b\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ by definition of the set $M_2$." Matrices on that form are very much contained in $M_2$)

EDIT: In fact, $\Psi$ is not even defined on a subset of $M_2(\mathbb{Z}^*)$, as $\mathbb{Z}^*$ contains only non-zero integers. See the comments below.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence that "matrices [of] that form are very much contained in $M_2$." The reason why these matrices are not contained in $M_2$ is because the components must be nonzero, which is what is meant by $a,b,cd \in \mathbb{Z^*}$. But the component in the first row, second column and the one in the second row, first column are zero, so how can such a matrix belong to $M_2$? It cannot, I think. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Oh! Now I understand your point, and you are absolutely right. I forgot about the non-zero bit. Disregard my answer. @benedict-voltaire

Comment: Haha, all good! Thank you for reviewing my question and answer.

Comment: No problem, and thank you for being sceptical. :) I've included your thoughts in my answer to avoid future confusion. @BenedictVoltaire